# In DDD/CQRS, should ReadModel act as ViewModel, if not then where belongs responsibility for mapping?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

Assume read model `ProductCatalogueItem` is built from aggregates/write-models, stored separately from write-models, and contains each product available for selling, and has following properties:

- basics: `product_code`, `name`, `price`, `number_of_available_stock`,
- documentation: `short_description`, `description`,...
- product characteristics: `weight`, `length`, `depth`, `width`, `color`,...

And, there are two views:

- product list containing list/table/grid of available product offers, and the view needs only following basic properties: `product_code`, `name`, `price`, `number_of_available_stock`,
- product details showing all the properties - basics, documentation, product characteristics.

Naturally, there come two ViewModels in mind:

- `ProductCatalogueListItem` containing only basic properties,
- `ProductCatalogueItemDetails` containing all the properties.

Now,.. there two options (I can see).

---

1. ViewModels are 1:1 representation of ReadModels

Therefore the are two read models, not one, `ProductCatalogueListItem` and `ProductCatalogueItemDetails`. And, the read service will have two methods:

- `List<ProductCatalogueListItem> searchProducts(FilteringOptions)`,
- `ProductCatalogueItemDetails getProductDetails(product_code)`.

And, controllers return these models directly (or, mapped to dto for transport layer).

**The issue here is filtering**,.. should read service perform search query on a different read model, than is returned from the method call? Because, ProductCatalogueListItem doesn't have enough information to perform filtering.

---

2. ViewModels are another project of ReadModels

The read service will have two methods:

- `List<ProductCatalogueItem> searchProducts(FilteringOptions)`,
- `ProductCatalogueItem getProduct(product_code)`.

And, the mapping from ReadModels to ViewModels is done by upper layer (probably controller).

There is no issue with filtering,... But, there is another issue, that more data leave domain layer, than is actually needed. And, controllers would grow with more logic. As there might be different controllers for different transport technologies, then mapping code would probably get duplicated in those controllers.

---

Which approach to organize responsibilities is correct according to DDD/CQRS, or completely something else?

The point is:

- should I build two read models, and search using one, then return other?
- should I build single read model, which is used, and then mapped to limited view to contain only base information for view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you do a wrong assertion:

> ...read model ProductCatalogueItem is built from aggregates/write-models...

Read model doesn't know of aggregates or anything about write model, you build the read model directly from the database, returning the data needed by the UI.

So, the  view model is the read model, and it doesn't touch the write model.  That's the reason why CQRS exists: for having a different model,  the read model,  to optimize the queries for returning the data needed by the client.

## Update

I will try to explain myself better:

CQRS is simply splitting one object into two, based on the method types. There are two method types: command (any method that mutates state) and query (any method that returns a value). That's all.

When you apply this pattern to the service boundary of an application, you have a write service and a read service, and so you can scale differently the command and query handling, and you can have also two models.

But CQRS is not having two databases, is not messaging, is not eventual consistency, is not updating read model from write model, is not event sourcing. You can do CQRS wihtout them. I say this because I've seen some misconceptions in your assertions.

That said, the design of the read model is done according to what information the user wants to see in the UI, i.e., the read model is the view model, you have no mapping between them, they both are the same model. You can read about it in the references (3) and (6) bellow. I think this answer to your whole question. What I don't understand is the filtering issue.

### Some good references

(1) http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/02/16/cqrs-task-based-uis-event-sourcing-agh/

(2) http://www.cqrs.nu/Faq/command-query-responsibility-segregation

(3) "Implementing Domain Driven Design" book, by Vaughn Vernon. Chapter 4: Architecture, "Command-Query Responsibility Segregation, or CQRS" section

(4) https://kalele.io/really-simple-cqrs/

(5) https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html

(6) http://udidahan.com/2009/12/09/clarified-cqrs/

Comment: That wasn't point of question at all. The read model is built from write-model directly, or indirectly using event sourcing, or any else approach,..And, then the built read model is stored separately in database, and doesn't know about write models,... The point is, that filtering needs read model with more information, than is the model  returned by the search (filter by product characteristics, but return only short summary for listing). So, should I build two read models, and filter by one, return the second? Or, should I do some else mapping for view?

Comment: Anyway, thank you for the effort to write the answer! Though, it answered some point I didn't mean,.. Can you please answer the main point of the question? (I plan to open bounty anyway, when this question becomes eligible for the bounty,.. as learning good code design is worth sacrificing some reputation)

Comment: I think you are wrong in some assertions of your comment. I will edit my answer later explaining it better and giving references. And I will try to answer better to your question,  although I think I wrote it clear.  Thank you

Comment: `you build the read model directly from the database` do you mean to build it directly from write-models? so, there is no read model built based on write-models using event sourcing, with eventual consistency? but,.. that contradicts `Read model doesn't know of aggregates or anything about write model`,.. so, read model is somehow built in advance,..

Comment: Thank you! Aha,.. So, to verify my understanding,.. I think, the only wrong assertion of mine was, that `readModel = databaseTableModel`,.. but, CQRS defines only application service boundary (towards outside), and the read model is a "DTO" outputted from application service,.. and, what happens inside (used tables to perform search), that is not defined by CQRS / read model. Am I correct?

Comment: CQRS just says to separate commands from queries,it doesn't say anything about inside/outside.You can apply it wherever you want.By your misconceptions I mean,for example: you think that CQRS says that you have to build the read model from the write model through events or something else.But you don't have to do it if you don't want.You can have just one db and do joins when you do the select in the read service method although it is not efficient.Another wrong idea you said is that read model is built from write model doing event sourcing.That's not event sourcing,that's eventual consistency

Comment: I thought, CQRS is some pattern more precisely defined,.. however, it's more vague, as it only defines idea/concept to separate commands from queries, and that concept can be applied on any layer/boundary,.. so, then maybe in some context view model is exactly read model, however, if there are some layers above layer where CQRS is applied, then read model might not be view model.

Comment: If view model is exactly read model or not, doesn't have to be with where do you apply CQRS. You could apply CQRS at service application boundary,  and design read model different from view model and do a mapping, but it is not usual. When I say that read model and view model are the same, I mean that it's the usual way,  because that's what you want to achieve (the read service returns the data the user needs). But of course you could design different read and view models, and do a mapping. But it would have no sense to do it

Answer (score 1):

As you already built your read model using data which arrived from one or more services, your problem is now in another space(perhaps MVC) rather in CQRS.

Now assume your read model is a db object and ProductCatalogueListItem and ProductCatalogueItemDetails are 2 view models. When you have a request to serve list of products you will make a query in your read db from read model (ProductCatalog table). May be you make queries for additional filters using additional where clauses. Now where do you put your mapping activities in your code after fetching db objects? Its a personal choice. You don't have to do it on uupper llayer aat aall. When I use dapper I fetch db objects using view models inside generic. So I can directly return result from my service method whose return type would be IEnumerable.

For a detail view I would use the same db object. I know CQRS suggests to have different read models for different views. But question yourself - do you really need another db object for detail view? You will need only an id to get all columns where in the first case you needed some selected columns. So I would design your case with a mixture of your 2 above mentioned methods - have 2 service methods returning 2 different objects but instead of having a 1:1 read model to view model have a single read db object and build 2 different view models from it.

Comment: So, if I understood you correctly, CQRS doesn't exactly define that? Well, there's already built product catalog as a read model, which is used to retrieve products and has got necessary filtering properties. But, CQRS pattern/architecture doesn't define mapping of read models to view? Therefore, it's fine to have one read model, and then mapped to different views in either application service or controller?

Comment: Exactly. CQRS only suggests that your query side should be segregated from command side. Its your responsibily to model query sides. You can use pure rdbms, nosql or elasticsearch for database layer. Modeling strategies for different storages might be different which has no relation with CQRS.

Comment: And, read model in CQRS is definition of persistence model (stored in DB) or read model is definition of DTO returned from application service? (as it seems the second, based on @choquero70,.. and, maybe that my wrong assumption is that it's the first (persistence model))

Comment: Read model is defined by yourself, according to what the user needs. Then you can built the read model as you want: persisting it in a db built from the write model (your read service just query that db), or you can build db views from the write db (your read service just query the db views), or you can build it in the read service (querying the write db doing joins)... it's up to you

Comment: ah, sorry, I am late into the party. As @choquero70 said, yes Its up to you. your read model may be directly persisted to db or it can be parsed as the model itself from another source e.g. your write model.